# It is posible to store the information of a php include into Memcached?

Tags: php, memcached, smarty

It is posible to store the information of a php include into a variable?
I use Smarty and 75% of my page loading time, 15 ms, is of one include:

```
require_once 'smarty/Smarty.class.php';
```

Would it be posible to save this information on first include into Memcached?

Comment: Not really, and it wouldn't give you the performance boost you're hoping for either. An opcode cache like APC will probably do a lot more (and 15 ms is hardly hefty).

Comment: you could load it in and then use `eval()` on it but ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, what you're looking for here is an "opcode cache" - an extension to the PHP engine which stores the result of compiling a PHP file into memory, so that that compilation only happens once.

The default option these days is [OpCache](http://php.net/opcache), which is bundled with PHP 5.5+, and [available separately](http://pecl.php.net/package/ZendOpcache) for PHP 5.2+

There are however other options out there; another term often used (although perhaps less often these days) is "PHP accelerator".